# SharePoint 2013 Item Search not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a site on SharePoint 2013, I have Custom lists, when I trying to search any item in the list, the search box doesn't return any results.
I did crawling(Incremental) on whole site and after crawling I did Re-indexed the list as well, but still the search box doesn't return any results.

I attached the image below.

[image]

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: In Site Settings > Search > Search and offline availability, can you confirm that the first settings is 'Yes' : allow this site to appear in search results. If this is ok, can you paste your content sources that are defined in search service application?

Comment: Yes it already set "Yes".

Comment: @Verthosa, I can't paste Content Source, because I don't have access right now.

Answer (score 1):

Check default item view form. I.e. you should be able to go to item and view it.
Sometimes, when default item view form is corrupted or not exists, crawler grabs list view form, but doesn't go through list.

Also try to check CA -> Craw Log -> Url View -> Type a URL...